# Cassandra Java Driver With Kerberos Security

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-jdbc

Am trying to connect from Datastax java driver to cassandra secure cluster with kerberos enabled.

Sample connection code:

```
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).withCredentials("username","password").build();
    Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
    System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n",
            metadata.getClusterName());
    for (Host host : metadata.getAllHosts()) {
        System.out.printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",
                host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());

    }
    session = cluster.connect();
```

**Am getting the below error:**

Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /x.x.x.x: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

```
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.waitForSaslCompletion(Connection.java:204)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initializeTransport(Connection.java:170)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:132)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:59)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:442)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:205)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:168)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:81)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:662)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$100(Cluster.java:604)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:69)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.buildFrom(Cluster.java:96)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:585)
at com.datastax.training.SimpleClient.connect(SimpleClient.java:32)
at com.datastax.training.SimpleClient.main(SimpleClient.java:148)
```

Am using DSE version 3.1.3. Java driver 1.0.3-dse.

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample you're using username/password credentials for authentication, which won't work with Kerberos. This blog post contains details on using the java driver with secure DSE clusters: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/accessing-secure-dse-clusters-with-cql-native-protocol

Comment: I did not find any error saying "Error obtaining subject for server identity". These are the server logs when I tried to connect

Comment: **/var/log/krb5kdc.log**

    Oct 18 16:32:37 <FQDN> krb5kdc[3112](info): AS_REQ (3 etypes {3 1 16}) x.x.x.x: NEEDED_PREAUTH: dse/<FQDN>@REALM.COM for krbtgt/REALM.COM@REALM.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
    Oct 18 16:32:37 <FQDN> krb5kdc[3112](info): AS_REQ (3 etypes {3 1 16}) x.x.x.x: ISSUE: authtime 1382113957, etypes {rep=16 tkt=16 ses=16}, dse/<FQDN>@REALM.COM for krbtgt/REALM.COM@REALM.COM

**These are the eclipse error:**

    Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /x.x.x.x